# How to increase multiple webview speed used in different Tablayout?

Tags: android

I made App like All in one Shopping App by coolwiks in which used multiple webview in diferent tablayout.But WebView speed is very slow.I used all coding for increasing webview speed with the help of internet,its not working.Please help me whats the Problem?

Comment: If you share some code, we could maybe help you...

Comment: code is too long..send me email id, I will give u  complete code.

Comment: How about following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code

```
// For API level below 18 (This method was deprecated in API level 18)
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH); 

webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
}       
else {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```